# Some absolutely positioned elements causes Firefox to extend beyond the screen

Tags: html, css, firefox, layout

I’m trying to achieve a specific layout which I’ve tried to show here: http://tmp.grytoyr.net/layout/

Basically I am trying to have multiple absolutely positioned elements with their own scrollbars. The challenge is to get the height of the elements correct, so that the scrollbars look natural. Another requirement is that left and right should always occupy 50% of the main content area.

In Chrome and Safari on Mac it works as expected, but in Firefox the scrollbars for the scrollable elements that have been pushed down by the headers (menu, left, right) extend below the viewport.

I am guessing this is because Firefox interprets height: 100% on an absolutely positioned element with some content above it a little differently than Webkit browsers do.

Is there any way to achieve the desired layout in all modern browsers?

**Edit**: I’ll answer my own question since I just figured it out.

I had added "box-sizing: border-box" which I thought Firefox supported by now, but it turns out I needed to add "-moz-box-sizing: border-box" too.

**Edit2**: But be sure to check out the answer by rgthree, since that is a much better way to achieve the layout I wanted.

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue. But whenever I am doing anything with CSS and I notice a difference between browsers I first check to make sure the CSS has been reset. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ This is where I would first look.And if that fails then I would start looking at other potential causes to the problem.

Comment: That’s good advice, but it didn’t make any difference in this case. But I actually figured out the problem in the meantime. I had only added "box-sizing: border-box", not "-moz-box-sizing: border-box". Adding that solved the issue.

Comment: If you've answered your own question, you should add it as another answer, instead of editing the question.

Comment: Cheran: I tried to, but I was told by the system that I needed to wait 8 hours. And I believe that editing the question to include the answer was mentioned specifically as a valid alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you cannot use height of 100% in this case, as that will be the height of the container and you have additional elements/padding/offset that is contributing to your overflow.

For instance, if a container's height is set to 500px, and you have a child content element with a height of 100%, its height will also be 500px. But if you start that child element under another element that is 50px (say, like a header in your example), then the total height is 550px (50px header + 500px "100%" content).

What you can do for your example, since everything is layed out absolutely, is use top/right/bottom/left. Here's the concept:

```
/* The container -- height/width doesn't matter */
.container {position:relative; height:500px; width:500px;}
/* A 50px tall header -- notice no width is set, but left/right is set to 0 */
.container > .header {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  height:50px;
}
/* The content under the header -- notice no height or width is set */
.container > .content {
  position:absolute;
  top:50px; /* 50px top to be below the header */
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px; /* Bottom is 0 so it will stretch the rest of the height */
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Now, just apply this technique to all your nested items and you'll be in business.

Comment: Although I managed to get it working in Firefox, I think your solution is the proper one. I must admit that I have never used the technique of setting both top and bottom for the same element, but it appears to work perfectly, and it allowed me do remove a bunch of helper elements and clean up the code. Thanks a lot!